# InnoDB Error - InnoDB: Error: trying to remove tablespace 264 from the cache but InnoDB: it is not there

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, aws

Im using AWS aurora which is MySQL 5,6 Recently I can see an error like below.

```
2017-02-14 20:42:34 2b2ca6a00700 InnoDB: Error: trying to remove tablespace 264 from the cache but
InnoDB: it is not there.
2017-02-14 20:42:34 2b2ca6a00700 InnoDB: Error: trying to remove tablespace 264 from the cache but
InnoDB: it is not there.
2017-02-14 20:49:56 2b2ca6a00700 InnoDB: Error: trying to remove tablespace 378 from the cache but
InnoDB: it is not there.
2017-02-14 20:49:56 2b2ca6a00700 InnoDB: Error: trying to remove tablespace 378 from the cache but
InnoDB: it is not there.
2017-02-14 20:50:41 2b2ca6a00700 InnoDB: Error: trying to remove tablespace 361 from the cache but
InnoDB: it is not there.
2017-02-14 20:50:41 2b2ca6a00700 InnoDB: Error: trying to remove tablespace 361 from the cache but
InnoDB: it is not there.
2017-02-14 20:51:10 2b2ca6a00700 InnoDB: Error: trying to remove tablespace 393 from the cache but
InnoDB: it is not there.
2017-02-14 20:51:10 2b2ca6a00700 InnoDB: Error: trying to remove tablespace 393 from the cache but
InnoDB: it is not there.
```

I don't know why its coming, Can anyone tell what its actually trying to say?

Comment: Did the server crash recently?  And you were in the process of doing something such as `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: Does this come up with anything?  `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%#sql%';`

Comment: Its showing Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: And my questions in the previous Comment?

Comment: No it's actuall a new server

Comment: Sounds like they messed up building the new server for you.

Comment: yeah, I asked their support, they are trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a AWS problem bug.
Please, see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=226520

Comment: Yes, its a bug. But it would be great if someone explains about this issue.

Comment: 'fix next release' from 2 years ago. Not very reassuring.

Comment: still not fixed ;)